# dynamic IFRAME has undefined body in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe

This works in Chrome but fails in IE11.  The end goal is to construct a new empty IFRAME, with a form in it, then to submit that form to display actual content.

The new constructed IFRAME has no `body`, so `document.body.appendChild` fails with error "Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference"

What is the right way to fix this and create an empty/placeholder body?

I think I can fix it with `document.write` but that feels wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/mobfrqxn/6/

```
var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");

var myframe = document.createElement("iframe");
myframe.src = 'javascript:false';
myframe.id = 'myframe';

placeholder.appendChild(myframe);

var newElement = document.createElement("form");

myframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(newElement);

alert("success")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your iframe hasn't had enough time to load so it's empty. 
Put appending the form into an onload function on the frame.

I've also put the whole lot into a window.onload to be sure that the main doc has time to load. This works in Internet Explorer.

```
window.onload = function(){

    var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");
    console.log('placeholder ' + placeholder);
    var myframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    myframe.src = 'javascript:false';
    myframe.id = 'myframe';

    myframe.onload = function(){
        var newElement = document.createElement("form");
        myframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(newElement);
        alert("success");
    };

    placeholder.appendChild(myframe);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the simplest fix seems to be removing the assignment of `myframe.src` altogether, since I don't actually want to load anything.

full example that I tested on IE9, IE11 and Chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/mobfrqxn/13/

Comment: about:blank works too, although that puts me in a gray area with same-origin policy.